# why I can't debug system_process when emulator boot in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have setup the environment of AS debug android source code, the steps as below:

1. modify SystemServer's main

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       android.ddm.DdmHandleAppName.setAppName("system_process", UserHandle.myUserId());
       android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();

       new SystemServer().run();
   }
   ```
2. make android-6.0.0_r1 source code
3. mmm development/tools/idegen/
4. . development/tools/idegen/idegen.sh
5. Open an existing Android Studio project from ANDROID_ROOT
6. set break at SystemServer().run() in main
7. launch emulator in terminal and it will stop at android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger()
8. In AS, I attach the debugger to "system_process"
9. Then emulator will continue execute, but it can't stop at break which I set in step 6

I tried the advice below:

[How to debug android framework services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226451/how-to-debug-android-framework-services)

but it not works

I can debug ActivityManagerService and other framework service when emulator boot complete, but I can't debug SystemServer, could you please help to check this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Instead of doing a debugger approach.. why don't you just use logs instead, will save your time.

Comment: Dear JoxTraex, thank you for your advice, but I have solved all the issue except this, and I hope someone can help me to solve the last one, :)

Comment: Dear sirs:
Could someone help me ?