# Remote debug AOSP framework services

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, adb, android-source

I am trying to debug one of the AOSP framework service, using Android studio 4.0. Some of the [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226451/how-to-debug-android-framework-services) I found online are using DDMS which is no longer present in Android studio.

Is there any alternative to set up the debug environment for the new version of Android studio ? Or is there any equivalent for ddms in adb that can be used instead ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

adb -d forward tcp:8700 jdwp:$PID ($PID is the service's proccess id.)

Then you can do remote debug with port 8700.